# Override method when constructing with different constructors in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an Android Kotlin app where I am using ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback.
The code looks like this (I have removed a few of the other functions for clarity):

```
    val cm = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    cm.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(object :NetworkCallback(FLAG_INCLUDE_LOCATION_INFO){


        override fun onCapabilitiesChanged(network: Network, networkCapabilities: NetworkCapabilities) {
            super.onCapabilitiesChanged(network, networkCapabilities)
            val ssid =
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
                    (networkCapabilities.transportInfo as WifiInfo).ssid
                }
                else {
                    (applicationContext?.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager).connectionInfo.ssid
                }
            Log.d(TAG, "onCapabilitiesChanged network: $network ssid: $ssid")
        }

    })
```

Problem is that the constructor NetworkCallback(FLAG_INCLUDE_LOCATION_INFO) only exists for Android API 31 and up.
For others, I need to use NetworkCallback().

This would mean I have to effectively write the code twice or create some second level to call. Maybe my own class that implements the methods.

Is there any way to do the inline override once?
Some way to choose which constructor to use and still do the override once?

Comment: Sorry, I think that at end you need to have a place where there will be if else statement. Of course, You can play with some fancy structures internal interfaces factory methods that depend on the device api.

Comment: I can't think of any possible way to do this cleanly. What an ugly API.